# Undefined reference error, even after specifying -L and -l flags

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile this package and keep getting an undefined reference to  error. I copied and edited the final compiler code in the makefile to make sure the external libraries needed are called before the other libraries.

Here's the error,

```
<path>/libqroot.so: undefined reference to `TLatex::TLatex()'
```

`TLatex.h` is in `<path>/ROOT/include` ,
`TLatex` is defined in the library Graf(`libGraf.so`) and is in `<path>/ROOT/lib`

Here's the command,

```
g++ file.cxx -Wall -g  -ggdb -fPIC -pthread -m64
-I<root-path>/ROOT/include 
-I/usr/include 
-I./ 
-I/usr/include 
-I<root-path>/ROOT/include 
-I<project-path>/pkg/base/ 
-I<project-path>/pkg/dianaglobal/ 
-I<project-path>/pkg/globalrw/ 
-I<project-path>/pkg//coretools/ 
-L<project-path>/lib 
-L<root-path>/ROOT/lib 
-lqroot -lcoretools -lmathtools -lbase -lgsl -lgslcblas-lGui -lCore -lCint -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic -lGeom -lMinuit -lSpectrum -lMathMore -lMathCore -lThread -lRootAuth -lFoam
-o <project-path>/bin//file
```

Obviously there are no newline chars.

Please help me figure what's wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure `-lGraf` is passed in, if the symbol is in libGraf.so.  The order of the link line matters.  For g++ a library containing the definition of a function should appear after any source files or object files which use it. So given the error you are seeing:

```
-lqroot -lGraf -lcoretools -lmathtools -lbase -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options

Further to you edit, this error will occur if your header files do not match your libraries.

Comment: oops, sorry there's a big space between so u probably didn't see it. (Sorry added spaces to distinguish those in the terminal, and removed all but this)