Getting "undefined reference" errors to Qt symbols with g++
I often write small C++ program as test code to understand using a C++ functionality, and just build and run them with g++ - quick throw away code that does not need a project and a CMake setup - could even be a single cpp file.
But when trying Qt stuff, I can't seem to get it to link - I keep getting "undefined reference" errors for Qt classes that I should have no problem linking with:
$ g++ -xc++ -std=c++20 -fPIC $(pkg-config --cflags --libs Qt6Gui Qt6Core) \
    -DQT_NO_VERSION_TAGGING -o /tmp/test-qimage ./test-qimage.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvBsBmI.o: in function `main':
test-qimage.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `QImageReader::QImageReader()'
/usr/bin/ld: test-qimage.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `QImageReader::setAllocationLimit(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test-qimage.cpp:(.text+0x118): undefined reference to `QImageReader::~QImageReader()'
/usr/bin/ld: test-qimage.cpp:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to `QImageReader::~QImageReader()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The output of pkg-config --cflags --libs Qt6Gui Qt6Core expands to:
 -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtGui -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6
 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtCore -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6
 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6
 -lQt6Gui -lQt6Core

What g++ flag am I missing?

-l... flags (which pkg-config likely outputs) must be after .cpp/.o to have effect.

When I saw this was about Qt and then read "quick throw away code that does not need a project and a CMake setup" I shivered a little. Qt is VERY unforgiving when it comes to trying to link to it without using a build system.

@HolyBlackCat - yep, that was the problem. I'm surprised I got away with the incorrect order for so long? If you'd have written that as an answer, I could have accepted it

I think some linkers (LLD?) don't have this limitation. Otherwise not sure why it worked for you before. I don't really want to write an answer, this is likely a duplicate.

OK, I found a dup, now that I'm not assuming its a Qt issue - https://stackoverflow.com/q/18052100/53538. Thanks!
